# Xamarin.Forms Embed phone # hyperlinks (0 to many) in text

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement that I provide a dialog that will display some text. In this text, there may or may not be phone numbers.
I have the regex for recognizing these phone numbers, so I know where they are.

I do not know of any solution to provide a way that the user click on the phone numbers and perform an action (the action will be launch the phone app, which I already have code for).

It appears that you cannot format portions of a label or editor, nor embed hyperlinks.

If I want to preserve the text format (not break it up) do I have no option other than handle a click on the entire label?

My only other idea was to take the text, parse the phone numbers, and dynamically create multiple labels, with each phone number being it's own separate label, which I could format as bold and provide a tap gesture action. The problem with this is the formatting.

Are there any other solutions that I am not seeing?

Comment: Maybe using a WebView?

Comment: iOS's `UITextView` has a `DataDetectorTypes` Property that can be assigned `UIDataDetectorType.PhoneNumber` and Android's `TextView` that you can `Linkify` phone numbers with `MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers`, but for a *simple* `Xamarin.Forms` implementation @Gusman suggestion in using a `WebView` and html containing the phone URI links would work (higher memory consumption / slightly slower in display rendering) instead of creating custom cross-platform control that uses "native" features

Comment: @SushiHangover sounds like that is the best solution but I have limited time to implement this so I will explore webview first

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using WebView thanks to the comment suggestion from Gusman.
I replace the phone numbers in the text with html anchors like so

`555.555.5555` - > `<a href='555.555.5555'>555.555.5555></a>`

I then handle the OnNavigating event, cancel the request, and instead open up the phone with the phone number obtained from the url.

WebView:

```
<WebView x:Name="EmergencyContactInfoWebView" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150" Navigating="OnNavigating">
</WebView>
```

OnNavigtaing event handler:

```
protected void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true; //cancel request
    int separatorIdx = e.Url.LastIndexOf('/');
    string phoneNumber = e.Url.Substring(separatorIdx+1); //parse phone number href from url
    var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
    if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
    {
        phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall(phoneNumber); //make the call (using a xamarin forms plugin)
    }
}
```